# insertAfter in jquery does not work when I use it with sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using droppable and sortable jquery plugin and everything looks good. The only problem I had was disntinguishing btw click and drop which I found the following link to fix it.

http://wowmotty.blogspot.ca/2010/07/how-to-click-or-dragsort-object.html

Here is part of my code:

```
  $("#content").sortable({
        items: "li:not(.not-dragable,.dummyNotActive)",
        revert: true,
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(".nav-item").css("pointer-events", "none");
            that.navBarListInOrder.list = $(this).sortable('toArray');
          },
          update: function (event, ui) {

          }).find('li').bind('mousedown', function (e) {
          // set time on mousedown (start of click)
          this.last = e.timeStamp;
        // clear moved flag
          this.moved = false;
          }).bind('mouseup mousemove', function (e) {
          // flag showing that the mouse had been moved
          if (e.type == 'mousemove') {
            this.moved = true;
            // no need to continue
            return;
            }
          this.diff = e.timeStamp - this.last;
          if (this.diff < 1000 ) {
            $("#" +       $(this).attr("id")).removeClass("dummyActive").addClass("dummyNotActive");
                $("#" +    $(this).attr("id")).hide().removeAttr("style").css({"background-color":    "#E5E8EC"}).insertAfter("#testLi").show('normal', function () {

                });
            }

          });
```

As you can see I have bind('mouseup mousemove' and based on the value I get for this.diff I run some lines of code. Now my issue is exactly here inside the condition: every lines inside the condition works except the following :

```
$(this).attr("id")).hide().removeAttr("style").css({"background-color":    "#E5E8EC"}).insertAfter("#testLi").show('normal', function () {

                });
            }

          });
```

even I can see jquery effect but the element does not get inserted in the right position which is after #testLi and it stays in the same position. The funny point is when I trigger inserAfter with click event it works fine. I do not know if this is related to sortable or I am using jquery.insertAfter wrongly. Can anyone help?

Comment: What error is showing in your console?

Comment: I do not get any error but I can see that the insertafter insert the element for a milisecond and then it will be back to its original position. Is it because of sortable?

Comment: Are you trying to add an element after `this`? `insertAfter` may be confused by the selector and not know what elements to add the `target` to.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Twisty thanx for answering I use 3.1.1